# How to know that User is still touching the screen in UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView. Typical tableView Cell. I did things a lot on viewDidScroll.

viewDidScroll is called on 2 cases.

1. User scroll
2. Sometimes user have stop scrolling but the scrollview still scroll anyway due to momentum, bouncing, etc.

So how do I know if users are still touching the scrollView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIScrollView` has a [`BOOL` property named `tracking`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW3) that is `YES` while the scroll view has a touch and `NO` otherwise.  In my testing, it is set to `NO` as soon as the touch ends, even if the view is decelerating (and still sending `scrollViewDidScroll:` to its delegate).  This seems like exactly what you are asking for.

In my testing, the [`dragging` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW2) doesn't seem to become `NO` reliably while the view is decelerating after the touch ends.

The [`decelerating` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW30) is also unreliable in my testing.  If I touch the scroll view while it is decelerating, `decelerating` remains `YES` even though the view has stopped scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

The delegate's `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` is called when user starts dragging and `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` & `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`(iOS 5+ without paging enabled) is called when user lefts his/her fingers.

You may also want to check `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`.

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

Comment: A correct answer. But rob's answer is way better. +1. Keep trying. good luck next time :)